# Can someone give me the example of this algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

This algorithm written in Write great code Vol 1 book, is for conversion of string of decimal digits to an integer value:

1. Initialize a variable with zero; this will hold the final value.
2. If there are no more digits in the string, then the algorithm is complete,
   and the variable holds the numeric value.
3. Fetch the next digit (going from left to right) from the string.
4. Multiply the variable by ten, and then add in the digit fetched in step 3.
5. Go to step 2 and repeat.

I don't know how the conversion takes place. Please give the example of this.

Comment: What does `example of algorithm` mean? What about trying to follow the instructions step-by-step?

Comment: @defaultlocale he wants code, most likely.

Comment: You didn't go to school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the string "1134"

```
String        Variable

()1134        0
(1)134     0 * 10 + 1 =    1
1(1)34     1 * 10 + 1 =   11
11(3)4    11 * 10 + 3 =  113
113(4)   113 * 10 + 4 = 1134
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* warning: naive and unsafe implement. don't use it for important projects */
int strtod(const char *str)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while (*str)
        ret = ret * 10 + *str++ - '0';
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your standard string-to-int conversion algorithm:

```
char *s = "12345";
int res = 0;              // 1. Initialize a variable with zero
while (*s) {              // 2. If there are no more digits in the string...
    int d = (*s++ - '0'); // 3. Fetch the next digit
    res = 10*res + d;     // 4. Multiply the variable by ten, and then...
}                         // 5. Go to step 2 and repeat.
```

Comment: It should probably say "if there are still more digits in the string", you can't "3. Fetch the next digit" if "2. If there are no more digits in the string..."

Comment: @h4lc0n I copied the lines from the OP, so the text there is to give the poster an idea of the code-to-algo correspondence. These are not "real" comments on the code, though.

Comment: oh alright, nevermind then